# Как объединить поиск и пагинацию в yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте, мне нужно сделать поиск и пагинацию. Используя gii сделал search-модель.
Для поиска использую searchModel -

```
$searchModel = new ObjectInfoSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

Для пагинации -

```
$pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $query->count(), 'pageSize' => 2]);
    $object = $query->offset($pages->offset)
        ->limit($pages->limit)
        ->all();
```

Для вывода в представлении не использую GridView, а использую массив foreach.
И вот получается только так:
Для поиска нужно передавать в массив dataProvider

```
 <?php foreach ($dataProvider->getModels() as $item) : ?>
```

А для пагинации - переменную $object

```
 <?php foreach ($object  as $item) : ?>
```

В первом случаи пагинация работает, но только не с первой страницы - с момента перехода на другую страницу в пейджере, когда формируется url все работает.

Так вот вопрос как объединить эти условия ??

Comment: Зачем вам переменная `$object`? Если я правильно понимаю то вы получаете в итоге то же что и в `$dataProvider->getModels()`.

Answer (score 1):

Предположу что ваш обьект `ObjectInfoSearch` возвращает `ActiveDataProvider`, данный класс уже имеет то что вы пытаетесь присвоить переменной `$pages`, то есть обьект `Pagination`.

`$pages = $dataProvider->pagination;`